# Php code to search from multiple table in databse

Tags: php, pdo

I have three different table in my database which i need to search content from all the table but is not working out because it has different attributes

here is my table structure

**table 1 name >> blogpost**

```
| bid   | title     | body          | author    |
|-----  |-------    |-------------  |--------   |
| 1     | new       | hello new     | you       |
| 2     | cast      | broadcast     | me        |
| 3     | hack      | who hack us   | you       |
```

**table2 name >> forumnew**

```
| fid   | ftitle    | fbody         | user  |

|-----  |-------    |-------------  |--------   |
| 1     | new forum | hello new     | you       |
| 2     | cast me   | broadcast     | me        |
| 3     | hack you  | who hack him  | us        |
```

**table3 name >> download**

```
| did   | file      | disc          | type      |

|-----  |-------    |-------------  |--------   |
| 1     | whoweare  | hello new     | php       |
| 2     | cast      | broadcast     | html      |
| 3     | hack      | who hack us   | c++       |
```

I use this php code to select from single table

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['postid'])){
$search = $_GET['postid'];


    $output;

    if(!empty($search)){
        $dsn = new DBController();
        $dsn->prepare("SELECT * FROM blogpost WHERE title LIKE :search LIMIT 10");
        $dsn->bind(':search', '%'.$search.'%');
        $dsn->execute();
        $output = $dsn->getAll();
        $dsn->free();
    }

    if(!is_null($output)):
        $html = '';
        foreach($output as $i => $row){
            $id = $row->bid;
            $title = $row->title;
            $cont = $row->body;
            $html .= '<article> <div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="'.$id.'" class="readmore related ret">'.$title.'</a> 
$body
</div></article>';
        }
        echo $html;
    else: ?>
<h5 style="color: #2f2f2f;">No related search found</h5><br/>
<?php endif;
}?>
```

Comment: edit your post to show which fields match against other tables and add example of search terms showing expected results

Comment: Nice @dbmitch i tried to get that table but didn't work

Comment: @dbmitch that how my table structure look

Comment: I'm not asking about table structure - I'm asking about the fields in each table that you "need to search content from all". I can guess you need a union query but you should describe the relations between the tables - and what you want back from the search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options here:

- Use three separate queries
- Use a `UNION`

An example off the top of my head for how you could do a union is like this:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM (
    (SELECT 'post' AS type, bid AS id, title, body AS description, author AS owner FROM blogpost) AS search_posts
    UNION
    (SELECT 'forum' AS type, fid AS id, ftitle AS title, fbody AS description, user AS owner FROM forumnew) AS search_forum
    UNION
    (SELECT 'download' AS type, did AS id, file AS title, disc AS description, type AS owner FROM download) AS search_downloads
)
WHERE title LIKE :search
   OR description LIKE :search
```

The trick is to select data from all three tables into a set of columns with the same name.

Comment: so i can return search result with this  `owner` and `description` and `title` and `id` ? what about post,forum and download at the beginning ?

Comment: I just added the `type` field so you could discern which table the record came from. You may not need or even care where it comes from.

Comment: I just test it and getting too many errors i need to output `content TYPE, DESCRIPTION and AUTHOR` as search result

Comment: Here is what i get `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias' in /home/blogpage/public_html/_inc/dbcontroller.php:57 Stack trace: #0 /home/blogpage/public_html/_inc/dbcontroller.php(57): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /home/blogpage/public_html/user/test.php(35): DBController->execute() #2 {main} thrown in /home/blogpage/public_html/_inc/dbcontroller.php on line 57`

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said `off the top of my head`. I was hoping you might be willing to learn a little and finish it up on your own. I made an edit, see if that gets you closer.